# How to generate QR code with Zxing 2.1 library?

Tags: android, zxing, encode

**The problem:**

Well, I´ve seen many examples how to do it, but in this library **(Zxing 2.1)** none seems to work. I want to encode a string into a QRCode and get the bitmap to show in a Imageview.

**Question:**

Should I use the older version? Anyone have a working sample with Zxing library 2.1?

**What I´ve tried:**

```
String contents = uniqueID;
        BarcodeFormat barcodeFormat = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;

        int width = 300;
        int height = 300;

        MultiFormatWriter barcodeWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix matrix = barcodeWriter.encode(contents, barcodeFormat, width, height);


        } catch (WriterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

And got this:

```
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at br.com.example.nightid.slidingsubmenu.IDcard.onCreate(IDcard.java:75)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-05 13:02:10.701: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And sorry If I'm doing a big mistake, first time using this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it right there. You didn't actually build these classes into your app. Nothing to do with the library.

Comment: Sorry, what you mean? I just imported the core.jar and used Zxing 2.1 as library.

Comment: Sure, in Eclipse, but your build for the Android app itself is not including the .jar file.

Comment: I have imported core.jar, any other .jar to be included?

Comment: You may have imported it but you are not *building it into your app*. Please read the Android SDK docs for third party jars.

Comment: @SeanOwen Is it possible to generate QR code with pre-defined QR version? like v04.

Comment: No... there's really no point in using a higher version than necessary. "Version" just means size.